# How can I easily open a specific product on another country's site?

Tags: amazon

I often browse products on `amazon.de`, but would then like to discuss a certain product online with an international community.

Is there an easy way to open a product page on `amazon.com` or vice versa?

Comment: It seems like you can simply replace .de with .com for some products. I just tried it with Apple TV. However, there are probably a lot of products where it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you search for a product you'd find a unique [ASIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Standard_Identification_Number) number for every product(ASIN is same for any domain), just use that ASIN number in search box in the domain you prefer, you'll find the product if it is available.

Comment: According to Wikipedia: "The same product may be referred to by several ASINs though, and different national sites may use a different ASIN for the same product." So that will not work, and a quick test suggests that it doesn't.

Comment: As for as I know, that's the only way we used while I was working for Amazon. It had worked me several times on several products.  By the way I cannot think of any other solution.

Comment: Well, thanks so far. If it only works for *some* cases, that will already help.